# When were "air quotes" first used?

Tags: folklore

When did speakers first draw in the air with their fingers to indicate that a word or phrase should be heard as if between quotation marks?

Comment: What connection does this have to mythology or folklore? Do air quotes feature prominently in some culture's mythology?

Comment: [Folklore includes customs transmitted person-to-person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folklore#Customs), and the [tag:folklore] tag is for "questions on the traditional beliefs, customs and stories of a community or culture".

Comment: Are you asking when they were first used, or when they were "first" "used"?

Comment: I've put scare quotes around my "air quotes", but then there's the much-famed role of the reader :-)

Comment: The better question might be "when were quotes first used in text."  (Certainly not in the ancient canons.  Seems to be ~1500's AD.)  Air quotes are almost certainly contemporary and only a recent custom.

Answer (score 9):

I found [two memorates](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=35093) from the 1960s describing the gesturing with fingers from each hand to draw quotation marks around a spoken word or phrase. These are recorded as witnessed in 1964-68 and 1968-69, by a then undergraduate and school student respectively. I myself recall the gesture from 1980-81.

The  practice became widespread at the end of the 1980s, at least partly because of the gesture's frequent use by Steve Martin on the United States TV show *Saturday Night Live*.

The earliest reference I could find to the term "air quotes" was in [March 1989](https://books.google.com/books?id=oEQ9G8e_zmQC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=%E2%80%9Cthe%20quintessential%20contemporary%20gesture%20that%20says,%20we%E2%80%99re%20not%20serious.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=3mNPgz8u2m&sig=KLqd9oTloSFLyhOrYptovNEBteQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixwdnlo97SAhUhxVQKHQ9XAA0Q6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Cthe%20quintessential%20contemporary%20gesture%20that%20says%2C%20we%E2%80%99re%20not%20serious.%E2%80%9D&f=false) by Kurt Andersen and Paul Rudnick in their article "The Irony Epidemic" in *Spy* magazine. (Some online sources cite a 1987 source for a use by Frazier Moore, but this [does not stand up](https://books.google.com/books?id=oEQ9G8e_zmQC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=%E2%80%9Cthe%20quintessential%20contemporary%20gesture%20that%20says,%20we%E2%80%99re%20not%20serious.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=3mNPgz8u2m&sig=KLqd9oTloSFLyhOrYptovNEBteQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixwdnlo97SAhUhxVQKHQ9XAA0Q6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Cthe%20quintessential%20contemporary%20gesture%20that%20says%2C%20we%E2%80%99re%20not%20serious.%E2%80%9D&f=false).)

There is a much earlier reference to a similar but not identical gesture in the July 1927 edition of *Science*, which describes a woman who raised her hands above her head with the first and second fingers pointing upwards, representing quotation marks, when she wished to convey that her sayings were not original.

Comment: I wonder when Victor Borge's _Phonetic Punctuation_ skit was first performed.

Comment: @David according to the Discography entries here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Borge a record came out in 1945 called Phonetic Punctuation part 1 and 2.

Comment: @Bent Well spotted. Those aren't modern air-quotes (the skit involves him reading a passage from a book while drawing all the punctuation marks individually in the air and making silly noises) but it seems relevant.  He'd draw an open quote, read the quoted text, then draw the close quote, rather than simultaneously making both quote marks throughout the quote.